# Appcelerator Titanium app can't compile with Streethawk push module

Tags: push-notification, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I am creating app which should use Streethawk push module, but when I try to compile it, than it freezes on running dexer.

When I try to compile app with module: com.streethawk.shanalytics it compiles perfectly, but if I will add com.streethawk.shpush than it will freeze on:

`Running dexer: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-Xmx1024M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"` with a long list of modules.

If I check Activity Monitor I will see it is using 100% of CPU power so it seems that it gets into some kind of a loop during the process.

After about half an hour it throws an error:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
[ERROR] :  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[ERROR] :   at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
[ERROR] :   at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.utf8BytesToString(CstString.java:158)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.<init>(CstString.java:200)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:371)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:262)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Any help welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is Streethawk's fault. I've created ticket on there support board and after 2 weeks I got an answer:

"I am sorry to inform that we don't have enough resources at the moment to attend and resolve the titanium issue.  My sincere apologies for the inconvenience caused."

So if you plan to use their module on Android than it is not possible now.